# Rails action cable with apache 2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, actioncable

I am trying to get a chat application working using rails action cable and apache. I am trying to make this work https://github.com/ScotchSource/ActionCableUploading, but no luck just yet.

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  # I have tried many different URI to be proxied, but still no luck
  ProxyPass /test-app/cable ws://servername:7521/test-app/cable
  ProxyPassReverse /test-app/cable ws://servername:7521/test-app/cable

  Alias /test-app /var/www/test-app/public
  <Location /test-app>
    PassengerBaseURI /test-app
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/test-app
  </Location>

  <Directory /var/www/test-app/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Made a few changes and tried different URLs in `config.action_cable.url` in environment/development.rb to point to the correct proxy in apache config.

I have read many blog posts and articles and tried different setups. Some people manage to make it work, but when I tried their solution it does not work. Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciate it.